# PrepareForLaunch

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

Я пытаюсь развернуть приложение ASP NET CORE на Docker .
Вот его структура:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл docker compose.yml выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема заключается в том, что после сборки приложения вылетает ошибка:

Ошибка  MSB4018 непредвиденная ошибка при выполнении задачи "PrepareForLaunch".
Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить?

Comment: Что в логах пишут?

Comment: Покажите, что написано в `TicketsApi/Dockerfile`